# handle request.js error in node application

Tags: javascript, node.js, requestjs

I am using request to access data from an api. sometimes, when the api Url is down, node throws error and shuts down with the following error

```
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)     
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:426:9)    
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)   
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)    
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)         
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',    
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',    
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',       
  hostname: APIURL
```

is there any way to handle this and prevent node from exiting?
my code is

```
const JSONdata= ()=>{  
 request({url:API_URL2,json:true},(error,response,body)=>{          
        const data=[]       
        var jsondata=body      
        data.push(jsondata)       
        const data2=JSON.stringify(data)        
        fs.writeFile('sample.txt',data2,(err) => { if(error){console.log(error} })})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use try/catch blocks that will keep your program running when certain functions error out. Here's a link describing how they work!

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp

Answer (score 0):

Firstly request module has been deprecated [request deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) hence you can try some other packages like axios. Also while trying out api as well as database request try to have a try and catch block and in case of error try to have an appropriate error message displayed to the user.

```
try{
//your code
res.json("success")
}
catch(err){
   res.json("Looks like something went wrong")
}
```